# ipsec between 2 computers

Tags: virtual-machine, ipsec

I am new in networks domain and I want to ask some question about ipsec. We create a client server application(chat) in Java (the server is multithreaded). This runs at localhost. For the assignment we were asked (for security) to incorporate ipsec in the app. Specifically we were asked to make the client check if communication with server is being made via Ipsec protocol.If no, then communication must be made through TLS. We have read many tutorials about ipsec but we cant undestand how to do it.

1)Do we need 2 pc?

2)If yes, do we need virtual machines to use windows 2000 (as many tutorials are about windows 2000)

3)Are we in a completely wrong direction?

Thank you very very much

Comment: You dont need two physical machines. You can setup two virtual machines on you PC and test ipsec. I would prefer to do it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally no way for the client to know that IPSEC is being used between the client machine and server. The IPSEC communication is happening at a lower level (level 3) than a normal application has access to.  It is like asking a client to decide the routing strategy for IP packets.

It is theoretically possible to implement a whole IPSEC stack inside a Java client, however it would require a lot of code, and access to UDP ports that require privileged access.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776369(v=ws.10).aspx

There are some tools on various platforms that might provide clues to whether communications are being secured with IPSEC e.g.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959541.aspx